# JavaScript not working in popup.html of Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I followed the steps to develop a Chrome extension from dev docs https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/development-basics/

But my popup.js is not working, even loading the "hello world" extension example from documentation the scripts remains doing nothing.

My extension structure:

```
extension
├── images
│   ├── icon-128.png
│   ├── icon-16.png
│   ├── icon-32.png
│   ├── icon-48.png
│   └── icon-64.png
├── manifest.json
├── popup.css
├── popup.html
└── popup.js
```

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My extension",
  "description": "Extension example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "images/icon-48.png"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-16.png",
    "32": "images/icon-32.png",
    "48": "images/icon-48.png",
    "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  }
}
```

Popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="cta-wrapper">
        <button id="cta-btn" class="btn">CLICK ME</button>
    </div>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Popup.js

```
document.getElementById('cta-btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('Click')
})
```

I tried with a simple console.log in popup.js but do nothing. Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: Is there an error in the console?

Comment: I tried this on my side and it worked. You are probably looking in the wrong console! The console for the popup needs to be opened directly by opening the pop up window, right clicking the pop up, and press "Inspect". Let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: @epascarello No errors are displayed

Comment: If you add a console.log line in the popup.js (not in the click listener) does it get triggered?

Comment: @GuillermoReyes Please read me comment. I recreated your exact code and it worked. I promise you the issue is that you're looking in the wrong console. Try exchanging ```console.log``` for ```alert``` and you will see it work.

Comment: @JoeRidyard You are right! I was on the wrong console. Thank you very much, I was already pulling my hair out ⭐

Comment: @GuillermoReyes No problem, I remember what it was like building my first chrome extensions - those kind of issues came up all the time hah!

Answer (score -2):

You should wrap `click` event registration code on window's `load` event.

Like this,

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.getElementById('cta-btn').addEventListener('click', clickOnButton);
});
function clickOnButton(e) {
  console.log('Click');
}
```

Comment: No you do not have to do that.

Comment: Yup, my bad.
I tested my code and it is working perfectly without load event.

Comment: that would not be the problem. he loaded the script after the elements were already present.